Why can I view $k(y_1)$ as a subfield of $k(z_1)$ when $z_1\mapsto y_1$ by a morphism of schemes? (Hartshorne theorem II.4.7, valuative criteria)
I'm reading Hartshorne's proof of the Valuative Criterion of Properness (theorem II.4.7), and I have a question. Here is the relevant setup, from the end of the proof, when trying to prove that a morphism $f:X\to Y$ of finite type with $X$ noetherian which satisfies the valuative criterion is indeed proper:

Conversely, suppose the condition of the theorem [the valuative criteria] holds. To show $f$ is proper, we have only to show that it is universally closed, since it is of finite type by hypothesis, and it is separated by (4.3). So let $Y'\to Y$ be any morphism, and let $f':X'\to Y'$ be the morphism obtained from $f$ by base extension. Let $Z$ be a closed subset of $X'$, and give it the reduced induced structure. $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Z\subset X' @>>> X\\
@VV{f'}V @VV{f}V \\
Y' @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
We need to show that $f'(Z)$ is closed in $Y'$. Since $f$ is of finite type, so is $f'$ and so is the restriction of $f'$ to $Z$ (Ex. 3.13). In particular, the morphism $f':Z\to Y'$ is quasi-compact, so by (4.5) we have only to show that $f(Z)$ is stable under specialization. So let $z_1\in Z$ be a point, let $y_1=f'(z_1)$, and let $y_1\rightsquigarrow y_0$ be a specialization. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the local ring of $y_0$ on $\overline{\{y_1\}}$ with its reduced induced structure. Then the quotient field of $\mathcal{O}$ is $k(y_1)$, which is a subfield of $k(z_1)$. ...

In the last line of the quoted passage, he says
"Then the quotient field of $\mathcal{O}$ is $k(y_1)$, which is a subfield of $k(z_1)$".
I get the first half of the sentence for $y_1$ being a generic point of the set $\overline{\{y_1\}}$, but I don't understand the second half--why is it a subfield of $k(z_1)$? Here $f'(z_1) = y_1$.
It seems that $\overline{\{y_1\}}=\overline{f'(\{z_1\})}\supseteq f'(\overline{\{z_1\}})$, so I tried arguing with closed immersions, but the inclusion would be flipped when we pass to the sheaves of rings, and hence the quotient fields (note NOT the function field here).
Any help is appreciated.

Making people who might answer your question click on a link and then scroll a bunch is a good way to get them to go do something else. Please put the relevant context in your post with an [edit] - don't leave it behind a link.

Thank you and I have updated.

Great, thanks for your edit to improve the post! Another thing that's encouraged here is to refrain from using pictures of text unless really necessary - I've written up what I thought were the relevant pieces of your screenshot in the post for this time and would encourage you to do so in the future. (See here for some information about commutative diagrams on MSE.)

Thank you for making all the edits and your helpful suggestion. I'm a little new here and will learn to use those tools for my future posts.

You're welcome, happy to help. Welcome to MSE!

If $f:A\to B$ is a morphism of schemes sending $a\mapsto b$, then the induced map $\mathcal{O}_{B,b}\to\mathcal{O}_{A,a}$ is local, which means that the composite morphism $\mathcal{O}_{B,b}\to\mathcal{O}_{A,a}\to k(a)$ factors through $\mathcal{O}_{B,b}\to k(b)$ (since the image of $\mathfrak{m}_b$ lands in $\mathfrak{m}_a$). Hence we get an induced map $k(b)\to k(a)$. As all ring maps of fields are injections, we can view $k(b)$ as a subfield of $k(a)$.
Now apply the above paragraph to your map $f'$ taking $z_1\mapsto y_1$.

I see. Seems that I forget about the morphism of local rings here. Thank you for the answer.
